# how to create spring data query if where conditions for internal Object's properies

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have create spring data query by using `findBy`

```
List<TaskEntity> findByUsernameOrUsernameIsNullAndDeletedIsFalse(String username);
```

the above method is working fine.
now if there in Another object in my current object `TaskEntity`, say `private GroupEntity group`, then how the above query will be?

I want to add groupId condition in above query.
like

```
 List<TaskEntity> findByUsernameOrUsernameIsNullAndDeletedIsFalseAndGroup.id(String username,String groupId);
```

.

```
Group.id
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Better use `@Query`. Your query method's name is getting way too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this according to [Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions):

```
    List<TaskEntity> findByUsernameOrUsernameIsNullAndDeletedIsFalseAndGroupId
    (String username,String groupId);
```

> Assume a Person has an Address with a ZipCode. In that case a method
>   name of
>
> `List<Person> findByAddressZipCode(ZipCode zipCode);` 
> creates the
>   property traversal x.address.zipCode. The resolution algorithm starts
>   with interpreting the entire part (AddressZipCode) as the property and
>   checks the domain class for a property with that name (uncapitalized). If the algorithm succeeds it uses that property. If not, the algorithm splits up the source at the camel case parts from the right side into a head and a tail and tries to find the corresponding property, in our example, AddressZip and Code....